# issue handling property containing brackets in handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to find a way to solve a weird property issue serve by server . For some reason server have to send some property in format like propertyname[] so when I have to get the value of the property containing [] is giving me parsing errors 
propertyname[] is an array

```
{{#if this.propertyname[].length}}
...some stuff in here
{{/if}}
```

there is no way I can read this weird property or maybe I am missing some basic thing  in here .  any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually handlebars allows you reference a property that is not a valid identifier such as ! [  @ # + * -, just use segment-literal notation to access a invalid property:

```
this.[propertyname{}] // it equals to this['propertyname{}']
```

Unfortunately, this method works on the premise that you don't use ']' in a path literal.

I think that change the property name (maybe use other character) or updated the data structure in the front end are possible way to solve this problem.